# Extjs: Mask component for modal window

Tags: javascript, extjs, z-index

I need to create a modal window in the other normal window. When I create a modal window is blocked mask.

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    var win2 = null;

    var win1 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        closeAction: 'hide',
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        resizable: false,
        titleAlign: 'center',
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'show modal',
            handler: function() {win2.show()}
        },
        title: 'Simple window'
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        items: {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'show window',
            handler: function() {
                var isRendered = win1.rendered;
                win1.show(null, function() {
                    if (!isRendered) {
                        win2 = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            closeAction: 'hide',
                            resizable: false,
                            titleAlign: 'center',
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                            renderTo: win1.getEl(),
                            modal: true,
                            title: 'Modal window'
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
}});
```

z-index is right:

- Mask component is 19006
- Modal window component is 19010
- Simple window component is 19000

I don't understand where I was wrong.

Comment: Your 2 lines are not enough to understand your problem .Please provide more details about problem if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you render `win2` into `win1.getEl()`. Normally, you don't render a window into anything, and let it take care of itself.

Indeed, if you remove

```
renderTo: win1.getEl(),
```

from your fiddle, the modal window is working.

If, for some reason, you want win2 to be modal only inside win1, you can use

```
floatParent : win1,
```

on `win2` instead.

Comment: Ya, I removed my answer.  This is one of the correct way. Here is fidler. [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c7b)