# How to add the Ext.window.window modal positioned inside another grid panel in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, modal-dialog

Modal window is added to the body by default. But,I want to add a modal window inside a panel when a add button click event. What code I have to add. Anyone suggest an idea.

Modal Window Code:

```
        self.sampleWindow = Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
        title: 'Add Deals',
        layout: 'vbox',
        closeAction: 'hide',
        padding: 10,
        cls: 'custom-modal',
        constrain:'true',
        height: (mq.matches)?"77%":"70%",
        width: (mq.matches)?"67%":"60%",
        margin:'31 0 0 -36',
        scrollable : true,
        items: [self.buildSample(),
               self.buildSampleGrid()],
        listeners:{
            hide:function(win){
                win.close();
            }
        }
    });
```

Panel Code:

```
var panel1 = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel",{
            id: 'dealInformationblock',
            minHeight:10,
            padding: 10,
            margin:(nq.matches)?'10 30 5 10':'10 10 5 0',
            cls: ['innerCard','card-layout-border'],
            layout:{
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'center'
            },
            items:[
                SampleInformation
            ]
        })
        return panel1;
```

Above modal window should be placed positioned inside the panel1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extjs: Mask component for modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880695/extjs-mask-component-for-modal-window)

Answer (score 1):

Use `showAt( x, [y] )` for showing the window.x & y should be a value which comes inside the panel.

Comment: The modal window have to be displayed inside the panel only after the add button click. But the above code position when the body get loaded.

Comment: we need to call this function to show the window...how you are displaying the window? By calling which function?

Comment: Thanks, resolved by using:
                 **constrain: true, constrainTo : "dealnformationblock", **  to window.

dealInformationblock is the ID of the panel.